# .net and java deployment

Tags: c#, deployment, installation

we have a website developed in java and .net. it works fine. but now we want to develop a installer in .net for the deployment of website. which should deploy both  modules means java and .net .
i know about custom installer in .net but how can i deploy java module through this installer???????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a standard Setup project in Visual Studio. Since we are talking about Java, all you have to do is place the right JAR in the right folder. You would do that the same way you would any other content file.

Comment: Dear jonathan, thank u very much for ur reply. can u please elaborate the solution little more. i got stucked in the situation.
i want to deploy java module on tomcat. how i can deploy application in tomcat using standard setup project in vs2008.

Comment: Take a step back and tell me how you would manually deploy a module to Tomcat?

Comment: we can just copy paste the war file in appweb folders or can use tomcat manger to deploy manger.

Comment: Ok, you should be able to just inlcude your war file in the Setup project and tell it what folder to copy the file too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to compile your Java files while making the installer?
In that case, you are probably better off using scripts to compile the Java files, copy them to some folder, and include that folder in your .NET installer.

Comment: i think u didnt understood the issue correctly.
i m developing a installer in c#.net for a website. the website is built in java and .net both. i m able to deploy .net part to iis programaticaly but not able deploy java part to tomcat. how can i do this through c#.